# php pdo: prepare() negatives become positive

Tags: php, numbers, prepared-statement, negative-number

I'm using a prepared statement to insert values from a form into a Db, and some of the values are negative.

```
# html
<input type="radio" name="opinion" value='-2' />
<input type="radio" name="opinion" value='-1' />
<input type="radio" name="opinion" value='0' />
<input type="radio" name="opinion" value='1' />
<input type="radio" name="opinion" value='2' />

# prepare
prepare("UPDATE $db.$dbt SET $question = :value WHERE `key` = :key;");
```

**Troubleshooting steps already taken**:
• I echoed the `POST`ed values from the form and negatives return negative.
• I copied the statement in the `prepare()` into the CLI and manually inserted a negative value into the same column where prepare is inserting the positive value:
`UPDATE db.dbt SET opinion = '-1' WHERE key = '10101';` (tickmarks present in actual SQL)
^ This worked.
• I printed the prepared statements as they're executed, and I noticed that the values are not enclosed in quotes. *I think this is where the issue is coming from*.

I read that values should not be quoted in the `prepare()`, so I can't think of anything else to do…

**EDIT:** The `prepare()` is inside a loop

```
foreach ( $pairs as $pair ) {
    list($question , $answer) = explode('=', $pair);
    try {
        $record_data = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE $db.$dbt SET $question = :value WHERE `key` = :key;");
        $record_data->bindParam(':value', $answer);
        $record_data->bindParam(':key', $key);
        $record_data->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e){};
} // end foreach
```

Comment: @Pekka: SMALLINT(4). I thought it might be a fieldtype issue, but I would think I would see the same problem when manually running the SQL in the CLI (and thus a negative number would not have been successfully inserted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using PDO :-

```
$sth->bindParam(':value', $opinion, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Default data type for bindParam is `PDO::PARAM_STR`

Comment: Is there a way to do this more dynamically? (Not all of the values are integers, and the `prepare` is in a loop).

Comment: Added it to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Well, is not that hard, change two line of bindParam and test again

Comment: If I add `PDO::PARAM_STR` to the bind, won't that misidentify the non-integer values in the rest of the form?

Comment: read carefully, asking to set to PDO::PARAM_INT, while the default data type is PDO::PARAM_STR

Comment: oh, yes, sorry I copied the wrong thing. won't specifying `PDO::PARAM_INT` misidentify non-integer values? (or will it realise text is not an integer)?

Comment: So I would somehow figure out the datatype of the current value in the foreach loop, and set `PDO::PARAM_INT` when it is an integer?